# JSONApi not working for polymorphic relationships. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api

I'm using this [gem](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources) and I'm having some trouble implementing a polymorphic relationship.

I have a `polymorphic` and `products` resource. And I have the appropriate controllers as well and the route. I also have the regular ActiveRecord models:

My models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Priceable

  belongs_to :producible, polymorphic: true
...
```

and I have this concern that I include in the `producible` classes like `Beer` or `Apples`

```
module Producible
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_one :product, as: :producible, inverse_of: :producible
```

My route:

`jsonapi_resource :products`

and

`/api/products/relationships/producible`

My resources (I heard I need the polymorphic resource as well).

```
class Api::ProductResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attributes :producible_type, :plan_id, :is_selling_enabled

  belongs_to :producible, polymorphic: true
end

class Api::ProducibleResource < JSONAPI::Resource
end
```

My controllers:

```
module Api
  class ProductsController < Api::BaseJsonapiController
end
end
```

and

```
module Api
  class ProduciblesController < Api::BaseJsonapiController
  end
end
```

I get this error when I try to navigate to the route listed on top:

```
{
"errors": [
{
"title": "Missing Parameter",
"detail": "The required parameter, product_id, is missing.",
"code": "106",
"status": "400"
}
]
}
```

it's weird since the route doesn't seem to require a product_id right?

Comment: Do you have a ```product_id``` in your producible models ?

Comment: So the error was the route I used. I think using the `jsonapi_resource :products` instead of `jsonapi_resources :products` caused this to fail for some reason.

Comment: I have a `producible_id` in my `products` table.

Answer (score 0):

As the error said, there is no `product_id` in your producible models. So your relationship `belongs_to :producible, polymorphic: true` doesn't work.

I think you want to have a `producible_id` in your product model. In this case you have to switch your `belongs_to` relationship into a `has_one` one and put your `belongs_to` in the producible model.

If you have any trouble about that, i recommend you to read the official rails documentation about [active record relations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

I hope this will help you